# capture all consecutive values varying from 2 to 11 entries in R

Tags: r

Recently @AntoniosK helped me figure out how to capture the first and last value of consecutive data points using the following code.

```
library(tidyverse)

f = function(x) {

DF %>%
gather(M,First,-ID) %>%                 # reshape data
group_by(ID) %>%                        # for each ID
mutate(Last = lead(First, x-1)) %>%     # get the next values in a new column
ungroup() %>%                           # forget the grouping
filter(First != "." & Last != ".") %>%  # exclude rows with . as value
arrange(ID) %>%                         # order ID (needed for visualisation purposes only)
select(-M)                              # remove unnecessary column
}

RDF <- data.frame(consec_months = 2:11) %>%
mutate(d = map(consec_months, ~f(.))) %>%
unnest() %>%
tbl_df()       # only for visualisation purposes
```

This was great and exactly what I wanted.  However, I want all of the values in between for another variable.

An example:

```
ID M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12 M13
1   5   15  2   20  .   .   .   4   2   7   8   .
2   2   8   7   6   5   4   7   4   7   9   9   8
3   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   7   7
4   6   7   8   6   .   .   .   .   .   7   6   5
```

The 3 consecutive answer for ID 1 would be the following:

```
ID  cons_months M1      
1   3   5   15  2
1   3   15  2   20
1   3   4   2   7
1   3   2   7   8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
ID M2  M3  M4  M5  M6  M7  M8  M9  M10 M11 M12 M13
1   5   15  2   20  .   .   .   4   2   7   8   .
2   2   8   7   6   5   4   7   4   7   9   9   8
3   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   7   7
4   6   7   8   6   .   .   .   .   .   7   6   5
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

library(tidyverse)

# create function that gets l as input (number of consecutive values) and returns a dataframe with those values as columns
f = function(l) {

  df %>%
    gather(M,First,-ID) %>%           # reshape data
    arrange(ID) %>%                   # arrange by ID
    group_by(ID) %>%                  # for each ID
    mutate(vec = list(First),         # save First vector as vec
           pos = row_number()) %>%    # save the position of this element in that vector
    ungroup(ID) %>%                   # forget the grouping
    filter(First != ".") %>%          # remove . values
    mutate(values = map2(pos, vec, ~data.frame(t(.y[.x:(.x+l-1)]), stringsAsFactors = F)), # save consecutive values based on position of that element and the corresponding vector
           flag = map(values, ~sum(.=="."))) %>%     # count how many . exists in those consecutive values
    unnest(values, flag) %>%                         # unnest data
    filter(flag == 0) %>%                            # keep consecutive values with no .
    select(ID, matches("X"))  }                      # keep columns of interest

# apply the function
data.frame(consec_months = 2:11) %>%
  mutate(d = map(consec_months, ~f(.))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  tbl_df()

# # A tibble: 87 x 13
#   consec_months    ID X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11  
#           <int> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1             2     1 5     15    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 2             2     1 15    2     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 3             2     1 2     20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 4             2     1 4     2     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 5             2     1 2     7     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 6             2     1 7     8     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 7             2     2 2     8     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 8             2     2 8     7     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 9             2     2 7     6     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# 10            2     2 6     5     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
# # ... with 77 more rows
```

Obviously, different number of steps means different number of values stored in columns. Therefore, some columns will have `NA` values if you want to store everything in one table.

Comment: Nailed it again.  Thank you so much.

I can just differentiate with that consec_months variable and be good to go

Comment: Let me know if I can update my answer in a way that helps you more. You can vote or accept the answer if you like it :)

Comment: How would I plot the differences of the mean of each column?  mean(X2) - mean(X1) and so on.